# Symfony 3.2 binding post values to form in REST api

Tags: php, symfony, fosrestbundle, jmsserializerbundle, symfony-3.2

I use following libraries/technologies:

JMSSerializer, FOSRestBundle + Symfony 3.2 + PHP 7.1

When I try to make POST request to my POST endpoint I can't get form to work.

Files:

Country.php -> POPO Entity

CountryType.php

```
<?php

declare(strict_types = 1);
namespace AppBundle\Form;

use AppBundle\Model\Entity\Country;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\IntegerType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class CountryType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('name' , TextType::class)
            ->add('iso_alpha_2_code', TextType::class)
            ->add('iso_alpha_3_code', TextType::class)
            ->add('is_numeric_code', IntegerType::class);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults([
            'data_class' => Country::class,
            'csrf_protection' => false,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getName() : string
    {
        return '';
    }
}
```

CountryController.php postAction

```
public function postAction(Request $request)
    {
        $country = new Country();
        $form = $this->createForm(CountryType::class,  $country);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
            die('ok');
            // TODO INSERT DATA then redirect
            return $this->routeRedirectView('get_country', ['id' => $country->getId()]);
        }

        return $this->get('fos_rest.view_handler')->handle(View::create($form));
    }
```

The problem is that it doesn't enter if block because both isSubmited() and isValid() methods return false. When I call `$form->getData()` it returns

`CountryController.php on line 40:
Country {#306
  -id: null
  -name: null
  -isoAlpha2Code: null
  -isoAlpha3Code: null
  -isNumericCode: null
}`

The request I make:

[image: Request to API]

Could you give me a tip what I do wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I do form submission when using FOSRest bundle, I hope this will put you in right direction. This is an example registration action. You will notice that you have to submit the form manually

`$form->submit($request->request->all());` and then check if it is valid or not

```
public function postRegistrationAction(Request $request){
    $form = $this->createForm(UserType::class, null, [
        'csrf_protection' => false,
    ]);
    $form->submit($request->request->all());
    if (!$form->isValid()) {
        return $form;
    }
    /**
     * @var $user User
     */
    $user = $form->getData();
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    //Set the user role
    $user->setRoles(array('ROLE_USER'));

    //Encode the password
    $password = $request->request->get('password');
    $encodedPassword = $this->get('security.password_encoder')->encodePassword($user, $password['first']);
    $user->setPassword($encodedPassword);

    $token = $this->get('lexik_jwt_authentication.encoder')->encode(['username' => $user->getUsername(), 'role' => $user->getRoles(), 'name' => $user->getName()]);

    $em->persist($user);
    $em->flush();
    $view = FOSView::create();
    $view
        ->setData(['token' => $token])
        ->setStatusCode(200);
    return $view;
}
```

Comment: Actually it was very useful. The key is that I need to submit the form in code with params from request. However your code won't work because when I return just $form as you do then I get error "controller action must return Response"

Comment: did you then try putting your logic inside the if statement after the form is submitted like `if ($form->isValid()) {....}`

Comment: yes after I used `$form->submit($request->request->all())` it worked

Comment: glad to know that it helped.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fetch data using the following lines

```
    $user = new User;
    $form = $this->createForm(UserType::class, $user);
    $form->submit($request->request->all());
    if($form->isValid()){
       //persist or do anything
       return $user;
    }
    return 'There were an error in your form';
```